# Docker: Clone git repo in current directory

Tags: git, docker

I am using [docker](https://www.docker.com/) to clone a public repository. It's cloned successfully. But I don't know where its cloned? Also how can I clone the repo in my current working directory using docker?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian:stretch

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN git clone https://github.com/ishpreet-singh/Sudoku.git
```

**Terminal**

```
root@ubuntu:/home/hp1/Desktop/src/sample# docker build -t img2 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/4 : FROM debian:stretch
 ---> 6d83de432e98
Step 2/4 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5ad3bd342683
Step 3/4 : RUN apt-get install -y git
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 29bdeb15539f
Step 4/4 : RUN git clone https://github.com/ishpreet-singh/Sudoku.git
 ---> Running in 613bdd58bc99
Cloning into 'Sudoku'...
 ---> ba9f61f10baf
Removing intermediate container 613bdd58bc99
Successfully built ba9f61f10baf
Successfully tagged img2:latest
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The repository will be cloned to the [`WORKDIR`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) directory which defaults to `/`.

So after logging into container you'll find the cloned repository under `/Sudoku`.

Cloning a git repo using docker seems to be a strange scenario? Why would one do that?

Comment: I want to setup the project environment so I choose Docker. Also, I want to clone the project and its dependencies. Is there anything wrong with the approach. With this anyone with docker is able to run the project. The above docker file was a part of the main file where i was stuck.

Comment: @Ishpreet, basically users clone git sources to their local workstations and setup a docker environment (which is a good idea) to run the project but with adding volumes with sources to the containers. So.. You should clone sudoku locally but use a docker container along with mounted volumes to run the cloned sources.

Comment: Also you copy the entire repor you might want a shallow copy